# Inserting multiple rows in mysql using korma in clojure

Tags: mysql, clojure, crud, compojure, korma

I am developing a restful application that uses Clojure on the back and Angular on the front. I have the following tables: Customer, Order, Item, OrderItems. I am using korma for communication with the MySql database. When I am making CRUD operations for all entities everything works fine. But I don't have any idea how can I insert multiple rows in the database? Should I use transactions in korma?

```
(declare customer)
(declare customerorder)
(declare item)
(declare orderitems)

(schema/defschema OrderItem
  {
   :OrderItemId schema/Int
   :OrderId schema/Int
   :ItemId schema/Int
   :Quantity schema/Int
   })

(schema/defschema Customer
  {
   :CustomerId schema/Int
   :Name schema/Str
   :Contact schema/Str
   })

(schema/defschema UpdateCustomer
  {
   :Name schema/Str
   :Contact schema/Str
   })

(schema/defschema NewCustomer
  {
   :Name schema/Str
   :Contact schema/Str
   })

(schema/defschema Order
  {
   :OrderId schema/Int
   :CustomerId schema/Int
   :PMethod schema/Str
   :GTotal schema/Num
   })

(schema/defschema Item
  {
   :ItemId schema/Int
   :Name schema/Str
   :Price schema/Num
   })


(defentity customer
           (pk :CustomerId)
           (has-many customerorder {:fk :CustomerId})
           (entity-fields :CustomerId :Name :Contact))

(defentity customerorder
           (pk :OrderId)
           (has-many orderitems {:fk :OrderId})
           (belongs-to customer {:fk :CustomerId})
           (entity-fields :PMethod :GTotal :OrderId)
           )
(defentity item
           (pk :ItemId)
           (entity-fields :ItemId :Name :Price)
           (has-many orderitems {:fk :ItemId}))

(defentity orderitems
           (pk :OrderItemId)
           (belongs-to item {:fk :ItemId})
           (belongs-to customerorder {:fk :OrderId})
           (entity-fields :OrderItemId  :ItemId :Quantity))
```

And here is my query to select customers that are paying with Cash with their orders and order items:

```
(defn get-customersbypmethod [PMethod]
  (select customerorder (with customer (with orderitems)) (where {:PMethod PMethod})))
```

My question is how can I insert order with order items?

Comment: I can't answer your question but, as the maintainer of org.clojure/java.jdbc which Korma uses, I want to point out that a) Korma hasn't been updated for several years (0.4.3 came out four and a half years ago) b) Korma is not very widely used so getting support on it might be hard and c) it uses a very old version of clojure.java.jdbc which is also no longer maintained (users are encouraged to migrate to next.jdbc). ORM-style libraries are not common in Clojure but if you really want that style, look at Toucan which is at least still maintained.

Answer (score 1):

The Korma documentation says the following:

Insert queries use the function (values) to add records. It takes either a single map or a collection of maps and returns the id of the first inserted record.

```
;; You can insert a single value:
(insert users
  (values {:first "john" :last "doe"}))

;; or a collection of several:
(insert users
  (values [{:first "john" :last "doe"}
           {:first "jane" :last "doe"}]))

;; You can also compose inserts:
(def base (-> (insert* users)
            (values {:first "john" :last "doe"})))

(-> base
  (values {:first "jane" :last "doe"})
  (insert))
;; Same thing as the collection insert
```

You can do transactions in Korma simply by using the (transaction) macro, which ensures that all queries executed within it are part of a single transaction. You can then use the (rollback) function to force the transaction to rollback if necessary.

```
(transaction
  (insert users
    (values {:first "cool"}))
  (insert address
    (values {:address1 "cool"})))

(transaction
  (if-not (valid?)
    (rollback)
    (do-complicated-query))
  (when-not (is-rollback?)
    (println "success!")))
```

Hope this helps. Korma is a stable and well-documented library.